# Laravel check Authorization header on requests

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

In Laravel, I use Sanctum for API-related requests. Currently, my main issue lies in checking the authorization header. I cannot verify whether it is present in the request header or not. For the following route, how can I check this header and respond with an appropriate message to the client if it is not included:

```php
Route::prefix('v1')->group(function () {
    Route::prefix('auth')->group(function () {
        Route::middleware([EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class, 'auth:sanctum'])->group(function () {
            Route::post('active-account', [AuthController::class, 'active_account']);
        });
    });
});
```

`kernel.php`:

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        //...

        'api' => [
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class . ':api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: `auth:sanctum` checks for that doesn't it?

Comment: @apokryfos no it doesn't wok

Comment: Using `EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class` would mean that sanctum will check if the token is present if you aren't already authenticated via the session (using the normal laravel session and session cookie). Is the question here how to differentiate between having authenticated with the session and having authenticated with the token?